# What is the testnet-magic argument and why is it 1097911063?

Tags: cardano-cli, testnet, query

I am currently running a testnet-node version 1.29.0.
To query the blockain, I use the command `cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063` to get the last block.

What is the testnet-magic argument and why is it 1097911063?

---

I got the command from https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The testnet magic, aka protocol magic, is a parameter introduced in Cardano during the Byron era. It is used internally by the protocol in cryptographic functions that construct addresses from a seed. Since this value is different in mainnet and testnet, the address obtained from a given path (or seed) is different in both networks.

Comment: But why is 1097911063? Are there other testnets with different number?

Comment: @G-Unit It's just an identifier, it could have been any other unique number, but I don't know why they chose that specific number. Other testnets used different numbers (I've seen the number 42, for instance)

Comment: Possible answer which explains a little bit more about this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/67191023/1336068

Answer (score -1):

A quick update if you are still having this issue then please use this command now

```
cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1
```

as testnet arguments have been changed. you can use both 1 and 2 based on your network preview or preprod.